# NumberFormatException when I try to create a parquet file with a custom schema and BigDecimal types

Tags: scala, parquet, spark-csv

I need to create a parquet file from csv files using a customized json schema file, like this one:

```
{"type" : "struct","fields" : [ {"name" : "tenor_bank","type" : "string","nullable" : false}, {"name":"tenor_frtb", "type":"string", "nullable":false}, {"name":"weight", "type":"decimal(25,5)", "nullable":false} ]}
```

Please, take a look at the field named weight.

This is how it looks the input csv file:

```
tenor_1;tenor_2;weight
1D;3M;1
7D;3M;1
1W;3M;1
1OD;3M;1
14D;3M;1
2W;3M;1
21D;3M;1
3W;3M;1
28D;3M;1
30D;3M;1
1M;3M;1
56D;3M;1
60D;3M;1
2M;3M;1
61D;3M;1
84D;3M;1
90D;3M;1
3M;3M;1
91D;3M;1
92D;3M;1
112D;3M;0.8333
112D;6M;0.1667
```

This is how I load the schema json file with its DataFrame:

```
  val path: Path = new Path(mra_schema_parquet)
  val fileSystem = path.getFileSystem(sc.hadoopConfiguration)

  val inputStream: FSDataInputStream = fileSystem.open(path)

  val schema_json = Stream.cons(inputStream.readLine(), Stream.continually( inputStream.readLine))

  logger.debug("schema_json looks like "  + schema_json.head)

  val mySchemaStructType = DataType.fromJson(schema_json.head).asInstanceOf[StructType]

  logger.debug("mySchemaStructType is " + mySchemaStructType)

  myDF = loadCSV(sqlContext, path_input_csv,separator,mySchemaStructType ,header)
  logger.debug("myDF.schema.json looks like " + myDF.schema.json)
  inputStream.close()

  //finally I create the parquet file. This line provokes the NuumberFormatException, concretely the line with .parquet(pathParquet)

  writeDataFrame2Parquet(myDF, path_output_parquet, saveMode,header,separator)

//some utilities 
def loadCSV(sqlContext : SQLContext, pathCSV: String, separator: String, customSchema: StructType, haveSchema: String): DataFrame = {

logger.info("loadCSV. header is " + haveSchema.toString + ", inferSchema is false pathCSV is " + pathCSV + " separator is " + separator)

sqlContext.read
  .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
  .option("header", haveSchema) // Use first line of all files as header
  .option("delimiter", separator)
  .option("nullValue","")
  //Esto provoca que pete en runtime si encuentra un fallo en la línea que esté parseando
  .option("mode","FAILFAST")
  .schema(customSchema)
  .load(pathCSV)
```

}

```
def writeDataFrame2Parquet(df: DataFrame, pathParquet: String, saveMode: SaveMode,header: String,delimiter:String): Unit = {

df.write
  .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
  .option("header", header)
  .option("delimiter",delimiter)
  .option("nullValue","")
  .mode(saveMode)
  .parquet(pathParquet)
```

}

When the execution reaches the last line, .parquet(pathParquet), an exception happens:

```
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows.
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DefaultWriterContainer.writeRows(WriterContainer.scala:250)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:150)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:150)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:88)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
**Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException**
at java.math.BigDecimal.<init>(BigDecimal.java:545)
at java.math.BigDecimal.<init>(BigDecimal.java:739)
at com.databricks.spark.csv.util.TypeCast$.castTo(TypeCast.scala:68)
at com.databricks.spark.csv.CsvRelation$$anonfun$buildScan$2.apply(CsvRelation.scala:121)
at com.databricks.spark.csv.CsvRelation$$anonfun$buildScan$2.apply(CsvRelation.scala:108)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:371)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DefaultWriterContainer.writeRows(WriterContainer.scala:240)
... 8 more
```

It looks like when spark-csv tries to render the "weight" field as a decimal(25,5), the library crashes. Anybody can help me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace commas with dots: `0,8333` to `0.8333`
Because, as you can see:

```
scala> BigDecimal("0.8333")
res16: scala.math.BigDecimal = 0.8333

scala> BigDecimal("0,8333")
java.lang.NumberFormatException
  at java.math.BigDecimal.<init>(BigDecimal.java:494)
  at java.math.BigDecimal.<init>(BigDecimal.java:383)
  at java.math.BigDecimal.<init>(BigDecimal.java:806)
  at scala.math.BigDecimal$.exact(BigDecimal.scala:125)
  at scala.math.BigDecimal$.apply(BigDecimal.scala:283)
  ... 33 elided
```

Comment: thank you for the help @ipoteka, but it didn't work. After I changed the csv file, the same exception happens. How can I create a parquet file starting from a csv file with a BigDecimal field within it in order when I load that parquet file with a data frame and that field is a BigDecimal?

Comment: @aironman Strange. And basically you would better have files in right format, then creating and mapping some stuff.

Comment: kudos for you @ipoteka. After I reviewed carefully the input csv file, I notice an empty field when the json schema file says that nullable is false in that field. arggg!

Comment: Yeah, this data cleaning is usually very exhausting activity.